# How to get a list of SObjects which have self lookup field on them USING schema class

Tags: apex, schema

```
public with sharing class listOfAccounts 
{
    public list<Schema.SObjectType> gl {get; set;}
    public list<string> listOfObjects {get; set;}

    public listOfAccounts()
    {

        getresult();
    }
    public void getresult()
    {
        set<string> gl = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().keyset();

        system.debug('######'+gl);
        list<String> allObjects = new list<String>();
        allObjects.addAll(gl);
        Schema.DescribeSobjectResult[] results = Schema.describeSObjects(allObjects);


        for(Schema.DescribeSobjectResult res : results) 
        {
            System.debug('sObject Label: ' + res.getLabel());
            System.debug('Number of fields: ' + res.fields.getMap().size());
            System.debug(res.isCustom() ? 'This is a custom object.' : 'This is a standard object.');
            map<String, Schema.SObjectField> checkMap  = res.fields.getMap();
            for(String str : checkMap.keyset())
            {
                Schema.SObjectField sobJectField  = checkMap.get(str);
                Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr  = sobJectField.getDescribe();


                if(string.valueOf(dfr.getType()) == 'REFERENCE')
                {   
                    if(string.valueOf(dfr.getReferenceTo()) == '('+res.getName()+')')
                    {
                        system.debug('final list of objects $$$$$$$$: '+dfr.getReferenceTo());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The list I am getting does not contain the objects which have self lookup fields on them

Comment: The code you have posted does not set the class fields `gl` or `listOfObjects`. What exactly do you mean by "list I am getting"; which list?

Comment: I meant the system.debug(dfr.getReferenceTo()); i am confused what should this return.. Could you post a fresh code for the task if you find my code wrong..? Thanks

Comment: See code in answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write code something like this (untested):

```
public with sharing class listOfAccounts 
{
    // Can reference in Visualforce as {!listOfObjects}
    public set<string> getListOfObjects()
    {
        set<string> s = new set<string>();

        list<String> allObjects = new list<String>(Schema.getGlobalDescribe().keyset());
        for (DescribeSobjectResult d : Schema.describeSObjects(allObjects)) 
        {
            for (SObjectField f : d.fields.getMap().values())
            {
                DescribeFieldResult dfr  = f.getDescribe();
                if (dfr.getType() == DisplayType.Reference)
                {   
                    for (SObjectField ff : dfr.getReferenceTo())
                    {
                        s.add(String.valueOf(ff));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        list<string> l = new list<string>(s);
        l.sort();
        return l;
    }
}
```

The [SObjectField.getReferenceTo](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getReferenceTo) method returns a list to support the (special) case where various types of objects can be referenced by one field. For custom objects there will never be more than one entry in the list.